# Changing feed tracking automated chatter feed post user

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, chatter, chatter-feed, chatter-feed-tracking

I have a requirement to update this feedItem post generated from feed tracking automation to say System updated this record or a specific user such as an integration user as opposed to display system admin user name who created the flow that performs the update. I have tried to do this by writing to the feedItem CreatedByID using both apex trigger and flow but it get exception with both automation (please see below screenshots), It seems feed tracking system generated posts have a type trackedChange which is not be editable even if a profile has CanInsertFeedSystemFields, I could be wrong. I would like to know if there's workaround around to change the user. ﻿
[image]
﻿

Apex exception﻿
[image]﻿

Flow exception ﻿
[image]
﻿